# Show that $2 < (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}< 3$ without using log or binommial coefficient

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$2 <(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}< 3$

Is it possible to show the inequality without using binommial coefficients thus only by induction? The leftinequality can be shown using bernoulli inequality.

Comment: I suspect the fact that $(1-\frac16)^{-6}$ is (barely) less than $3$ will be relevant.

Comment: If this must be true for all $n$ then it is false unless you change the first inequality to $\le$.

Comment: You can find a proof by creative telescoping at page 106 [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view)

Comment: yes n>1 and I am looking for a proof that would only use  tje ordering axioms and or induction. It is one of the first exc. of my book we have not introduced binommial coefficients yet or sequences or log so it wouldnt make sense using these methods in a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$. For any $n>1$ the inequality $a_n>2$ is trivial.
 We have $a_{n+1}>a_n$ by AM-GM:
$$\sqrt[n+1]{1\cdot a_n} = \text{GM}\left(1,1+\tfrac{1}{n},\ldots,1+\tfrac{1}{n}\right) \stackrel{\text{AM-GM}}{<} \tfrac{1}{n+1}\left[1+n\cdot\left(1+\tfrac{1}{n}\right)\right] = 1+\tfrac{1}{n+1}.$$
Additionally:
$$ \frac{a_{2n}}{a_n} = \left(1+\frac{1}{4n(n+1)}\right)^n \leq \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4(n+1)}} = 1+\frac{1}{4n+3}$$
hence for any $N\geq 1$ we have:
$$ a_N \leq a_1 \prod_{k\geq 0}\left(1+\frac{1}{4\cdot 2^k+3}\right)=\frac{16}{7}\prod_{k\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{1}{4\cdot 2^k+3}\right)\leq \frac{16}{7}\prod_{k\geq 1}\frac{1+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}}{1+\frac{1}{2^{k+2}}}=\frac{20}{7}.$$

Comment: We have not introduced roots yet but I searched for the definition of telescoping in the link you provided. And I noticed that there were some similarities with a formula that was in the scnd. exc. of my book (this question deals with the third exc.) the formula which had to be proved is $ a^{n+1} - b^{n+1} = (a-b)(\sum_{i=0}^{n} a^{n-i}b^{i})$ do you think I can use this somehow to prove this inequality?

Comment: What is AM  and GM?

Comment: @RM777: Arithmetic mean and geometric mean.

Answer (score 0):

You have the left inequality already (Bernoulli).

The right inequality can be expressed as 
$$
{n} \log (1+\frac{1}{n}) < \log 3
$$
Now $\log(1+x) < x$  by concavity, which gives $1 < \log 3$ which is true.

Comment: Most courses that still wonder about the size of $(1+\frac1n)^n$ do not yet have the log function at hand, I am afraid

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my problem in a different forum:

We show that $b_n > b_{n+1}$ with $b_n:= (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$

Proof:

To show: $\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}\geq 1$

$\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}} = \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+2}} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}} \cdot \left(\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n+1}}\right)^{n+2} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}} \cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{n(n+2)}\right)^{n+2}$

Exploiting the bernoulli inequality

$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}} \cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{n(n+2)}\right)^{n+2} \geq 1$

$b_5 < 3$ and $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n < b_n $

Thus $\forall n\geq 5: (1+\frac{1}{n})^n < 3$