# Is it possible to show only by induction and without the binomial theorem that $(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1} - (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} < 1$?

Tags: inequality, induction

If I could show that than it would be equivalent to say that there is no natural number in the interval $ (2,(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n})] \Rightarrow (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} < 3 $

Comment: I want to show what's on the right side of the implication but binommialcoefficients or logarithmus or roots were not introduced yet. That's because I am looking for a very specific solution to this problem. Maybe itcan be solvedby using the method of supremum and infinum.

Comment: You have [already asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2987534/show-that-2-1-frac1nn-3-without-using-log-or-binommial-coefficien) how to prove $e<3$ without binomial coefficients, and $\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<1$ is not equivalent to $e<3$.

Comment: Additionally, I have already answered you that you may prove $e<3$ (actually $e<\frac{20}{7}$) by telescopic products only, page 106 [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view).

Comment: Can you please tell me which pages of the book do I have to read in order to understand the proof? All the pages prior to the proof?

Comment: No one, the proof is a one-liner, once you know that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$\Bigl(1+\dfrac1{n+1}\Bigr)^{\!n+1}<\mathrm e$. On the other hand, $\Bigl(1+\dfrac1n\Bigr)^{\!n}>1+n\cdot\dfrac1n=2$ (*Bernoulli's inequality*), so
$$\Bigl(1+\dfrac1{n+1}\Bigr)^{\!n+1}-\Bigl(1+\dfrac1n\Bigr)^{\!n}<\mathrm e-2.$$

Comment: Alternatively you can use the fact that $(1 + 1/n)^n$ is increasing to show that $(1+1/n)^n \geq (1+1)^1 = 2$.

Comment: Yes, but it's harder to prove than Bernoulli.