# Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{-n}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I wrote out the term from above and get

$\text{Show that: }\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{n^k}{k!}=0$

I can use Leibniz' Criterion to find out that it converges but I don't know nothing about the value. Is there a $0$ convergent upper bound for this expression. Can somebody give me a hint how to find it please?

Edit: I have changed the fraction in the expression

Comment: $e^{-n} = \frac{1}{e^n}$ also $2<e$ and $2^n\rightarrow\infty$ so $\frac{1}{2^n}\rightarrow 0$ and $1/e<1/2$

Comment: This is just a special case of the general fact: if $|x|<1$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n=0$.

Comment: Although $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{n^k}{k!}=0 $ is true, you cannot prove it by looking at the terms of this series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the standard elementary proof that
$a^n \to 0$
if $0 < a < 1$.

$a =1/(1+b)$ where $b = 1/a -1 > 0$.

By Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+b)^n \ge 1+bn > bn$
so
$a^n =1/(1+b)^n
< 1/(bn)
\to 0$
as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Okay I understood it now however Prior to that I had to understand that the Approximation of $e$ is between 2 and 3- Like @GEdgar said in the comment it is apperantly not very easy to proof the Statement by looking at the Definition of the exponential function, ie. the Terms of the series.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2987534/show-that-2-1-frac1nn-3-without-using-log-or-binommial-coefficien     https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084932/show-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty1-frac1nn-lim-n-rightarrow-infty

Answer (score 0):

For any $a$ such that $0 < a < 1$, you can find natural $n$ to make $a^n$ smaller than any positive number $x$:

$a^n < x \iff n \, log(a) < log(x) \iff n > log(x)/log(a)$

Also, $a^n > 0$ for any natural $n$.

These 2 facts imply $lim_{n -> \infty} \, a^n = 0$

Answer (score 0):

Do not expand, just use

$$e^{-n}=(e^{-1})^n$$ which is quickly decreasing.