# Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{v=0}^{n}\frac{x^v}{v!}:=\sum_{v=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^v}{v!}$

Tags: exponential-function, proof-explanation

I have a hard time to understand a certain part of the proof below

Let $e_n:=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ and $s_n:=\sum_{v=0}^{n}\frac{x^v}{v!}$

According to the binomial Theorem we have

$$e_n=1+n\cdot\frac{1}{n}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}+...+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...1}{n^n}$$

$$=1+1+\frac{1}{2!}(1-\frac{1}{n})+...+\frac{1}{n!}(1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{2}{n})...(1-\frac{n-1}{n})$$

$$<s_n(1)$$

this gives us

$$e=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e_n\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n(1)=\exp(1)$$

**What is the justification for the $\leq$ symbol?**

I know the limits exists, the left Limit was proved by constructing nested intervals $I_n=[(1+\frac{1}{n})^n,(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}]$, the right Limit exists because of the quotient criterion.

The proof continues with:

Let $k>n$

Then

$$e_k>1+1+\frac{1}{2!}(1-\frac{1}{k})+...+\frac{1}{n!}(1-\frac{1}{k})(1-\frac{2}{k})...(1-\frac{n-1}{k})(*)$$

If we fixate a $n$ and let $k$ approach infinity we get $e\geq s_n(1)$ (**Why?**) which gives us

$$e\geq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n(1)$$

**What was the logic of fixating a $k$ and why is it still the same Limit after the Fixation and why are we allowed to do that ?**

Please shed some light on those equations.

Comment: It's because $e_n<s_n(1)$.

Comment: For the second question, the lower bound is obtained by taking only the first $(n+1)$ terms of the expansion of $e_k$ and dropping the rest. Since all the terms appearing in the binomial expansion of $e_k$ is positive, dropping some terms will only lower the value.

Comment: @SangchulLee I think I have understood a little bit now correct me if I am wrong but the answer to my first Question is actually a rule for limits. And to my second question  the Supremum of the Right side of (*) is $s_n(1)$ therefor the smallest upperbound, and because $e_k$ is also an upper Bound we have  $e\geq e_k\geq s_n(1)$ but I still dont know why $e\geq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n(1)$ what is the explaination for that?

Comment: Okay I think I got it now because $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}:e>s_n(1)$. We know that $e$ is an upper bound. Because $s_n(1)$ is monotonously rising the Limit of $s_n(1)$ also must be the Supremum ,i.e. the smallest upperbound that's why $e\geq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n(1)$

Comment: For a more transparent way of explaining the second step is that, taking limit as $k\to\infty$ to the second step, \begin{align*}e=\lim_{k\to\infty} e_k&\geq \lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{p=0}^{n} \frac{1}{p!}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{p-1}{k}\right)\\&=\sum_{p=0}^{n} \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{p!}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{p-1}{k}\right)=\sum_{p=0}^{n}\frac{1}{p!}=s_n(1).\end{align*} Now this inequality gives an upper bound of the sequence $(s_n(1))_{n=1}^{\infty}$, and so, taking $n\to\infty$ shows $$e\geq\lim_m s_n(1).$$